# Google sheets - Json to Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using this Google App script

```
   // Reference: https://www.labnol.org/code/20068-blogger-api-with-google-apps-script

function bloggerAPI() {

      var api = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs";

      var headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken()
      };

      var options = {
        "headers": headers,
        "method" : "GET",
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
      };

      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api, options);

      var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

      for (var i in json.items) {
        Logger.log("[%s] %s %s", json.items[i].id, json.items[i].name, json.items[i].url);
      }
    }
```

How can I import the values that are in the Logger.log into my sheet.

Comment: Use `Logger.getLogs` and the normal practice of writing data to the spreadsheet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the Logger.log() for [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#appendrowrowcontents).
In your case you have to set the sheet you want to insert the values:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Gets the Active Spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID OF THE SPREADSHEET"); // Alternative way of getting a Spreadsheet

var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // Gets the first sheet
var sheet = ss.getSheets().getSheetByName("Sheet4"); // Gets the sheet with the name Sheet4
```

Once you have the Spreadsheet you want, inside the for loop, you insert the values:

```
sheet.appendRow([json.items[i].id, json.items[i].name, json.items[i].url]);
```